# gnu sort --stable option not working

Tags: sort

I want to sort a text file with GNU `sort`, by the first field, with field separator ":":

```sh
$ cat aa
a:895502/
a:2013-05-24
# without --stable, last resort comparison
$ cat aa | sort -t: -k1
a:2013-05-24
a:895502/
# with --stable, should disable resort comparison
$ cat aa | sort --stable -t: -k1 
a:2013-05-24
a:895502/
```

The last output baffles me, since I expected to get back the contents of the original file. Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Sort by first field would be `sort --stable -t: -k1,1`

Comment: `-k1` means the key starts with field 1 and continues through the end of the line, since you don't have an ending field in the key.

Comment: Thank you, and @don_crissti as well. Sorry for not reading the manpage fully.